# Macbook USB Hub - Device ejected not properly error

Tags: macos, hard-drive, usb, sd-card

I have been using a MacBook Pro 2019 with a [Fitfort USB-C-Hub-Multiport-Adapter 7 in 1](https://www.chip.de/bestenlisten/100/product/939007/Fitfort-USB-C-Hub-Multiport-Adapter-7-in-1.html) (technical data below) for the last 2 years. I really like this USB Hub for its multiple ports as I use external display and all my USB ports are busy as well with external devices.

Everything was fine till today when I wasn’t able to connect my HDD and Camera SD Card. It simply shows on for a second a message “Disk/Card ejected not properly” and disappears.

**What I have tried so far:**
Free all the ports and connect one by one - didn’t help.
Reset NVRAM/PRAM - same situation.

**Things that still work with USB Hub:**
Keyboard, Mouse, HDMI Display, USB Flashdriver 1Gb

**What is not working:**
HDD 4TB & 512Gb, Camera SD Card.

**My question:**
So I try to figure out if the USB Hub is dead or something goes wrong with USB ports on Macbook itself.   Maybe there is not enough power for the HDD? How can I improve it and what may be the reason for it?

It would be a huge help if someone have faced same issues and could share its experience!

---

**Technical data**

I didn't find the USB hub on Amazon or on the manufacturer website as it seems to be no longer available on the market anymore. This is the information available (translated to English) from the [link above](https://www.chip.de/bestenlisten/100/product/939007/Fitfort-USB-C-Hub-Multiport-Adapter-7-in-1.html).

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. Can you add the USB hub manufacturer and model to your question (a link to the product page on the manufacturer's website or, if you bought it online, to the retailer's website would help too)?

Comment: Hi @jaume, thanks for the response! I updated my question with some links to the USB Hub in the description. I'm already looking for another model, but I'm not really sure what should I pay attention to. Maybe on Dockstation? Will it provide enough power for external devices?

Comment: Thank you, I have the impression the adapter is failiing, but to be sure, can you test it with another Mac or with a PC? That would definitely help identify the culprit. (I've added a screenshot of the technical data (translated to English) and a picture of the adapter for future reference.)

Comment: Hey @jaume its very kind of you to do some extra work for my post, I really appreciate it! Well, I will try to find another hub, but it might take some time through.

Comment: You're welcome :-) I own two USB adapters (USB-A, HDMI, microSD/SD slot, Ethernet) from LMP and Lindy and am quite happy with them. If you have any chance to test your USB adapter with another computer, it'd be great if you could post the results.

Comment: Just a short update to my situation. I know its been a while already and I couldn't find another Mac but I had a chance to try another USB Hub with my Mac so far, and it worked actually fine, I didn't notice any eject errors. 

As for my USB hub which I wrote this post about, I still continue to use it. I primarily use it to connect my mouse, external keyboard, and display. When I need to connect another power hungry device (e.g. HDD) I disconnect my external display and it works well.

I know that it's only a temporary solution, so I will look for some kind dock station in the future.

Comment: That's great news, thanks for the update. Going back to your question: *So I try to figure out if the USB Hub is dead or something goes wrong with USB ports on Macbook itself.   Maybe there is not enough power for the HDD? How can I improve it and what may be the reason for it?* It looks like the USB adapter isn't dead, and the ports on your MacBook are OK, so it is most probably a power issue, since the HDD works fine when you disconnect your external display. You may want to add that information as an answer, and edit it in the future if necessary.